# Lock type when updating non autoincrement rows belonging to an INNODB table

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, innodb

I'm facing the following problem,

I need to **update** an InnoDB table which primary key is an auto increment field.
The update operation doesn't affect the primary key itself (I'm actually updating only a BLOB field inside the table).

I have been wondering whether performing this kind of operation permits concurrent updates to be carried out (via row level locks) or whether it forces all of the operations to be serialized (in other words if it causes a table level lock).

In the last case, could I solve the problem removing the BLOB field from the table and creating a new table referenced by a specific foreign key?

Comment: What makes you suspect updating BLOBs would cause table-level locks? I'd be really surprised if that was the case. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is the answer I was looking for. I really didn't find it in mysql reference doc, and though what you said makes perfect sense I needed someone's else opinion to support my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

This should use row-level locks, so your transactions won't be serialized.